# Why does google cloud build run differently for these two commands?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

We run these two commands (the first one is async and the other runs synchronously)

```
#async BUT does something funky and doesn't run the Dockerfile image as-is
gcloud alpha builds triggers run staging-deploy --branch master

# sync BUT runs the image the way it's supposed to run!!!
gcloud builds submit --config cloudbuild.yaml
```

both are using our cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/continuous-deploy
  args: ['${_SERVICE}', '${_DOWNLOAD_URL}']
  timeout: 1000s
substitutions:
    _SERVICE: none
    _DOWNLOAD_URL: none
timeout: 1100s
```

Our Dockerfile is very very simple

```
FROM gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:alpine

RUN mkdir -p ./monobuild
COPY . ./monobuild/
WORKDIR "/monobuild"
#NOTE: This file in google cloud build trigger MUST be in root of monorepo BUT I don't know why
#NOTE: This command receives any arguments to docker
#ie. for "docker run {image} {args}", it receives the args
ENTRYPOINT ["./downloadAndExtract.sh"]
```

Sooo, when I run the SECOND command, it completely uses the docker image obeying the Dockerfile.  When I run the first command, it's ignoring all my Dockerfile stuff and trying to run scripts in my git repo(which is very frustrating and not what I want).

We HAD this directory structure

```
- gitroot
   - stagingDeploy
        - Dockerfile
        - deployStaging.sh # part of Dockerfile
        - cloudbuild.yaml
   - prodDeploy
        - Dockerfile
        - prodDeploy.sh #part of Docker file
        - cloudbuild.yaml
```

Of course, only the second command works with this directory structure.  The first command CANNOT find deployStaging.sh UNTIL we ln -s stagingDeploy/deployStaging.sh from our gitrepo root and we have around 5 deploy directories and now our git repo root is fully polluted.

It is to say the least very frustrating and we are not sure how to clean this up so prodDeploy contains all the prod deploy scripts and staging, the staging ones and get rid of all root files.

Of course, we now have a corrupted git repo directory structure with a whole slew of files in the root directory from various different builds(sometimes conflicting on accident as files get the same names sometimes).

EDIT: Not really much to share on configuration of twitter as each one just points to the yaml file is all like so

[image]
thanks,
Dean

Comment: Can you share the configuration of your trigger?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I added a picture though they just point to the yaml file so there is really nothing to share there.  We have software that calls the trigger to run when we need OR we just run gcloud alpha builds triggers run staging-deploy --branch master BUT mostly just do it via software.  ps. The api call acts just like the first gcloud command not the second as well.  Only the synchronous ones behaves in a way that I would consider 'correct' running the Docker image as expected.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere picture might be easy to miss but it's the last line of the SO post (small sliver).

Comment: What's happen if you go to the root dir of your project and launch `gcloud builds submit --config stagingDeploy/cloudbuild.yaml`. Is the same behavior of the async or the sync command?

Comment: ah, ok, that solves my issue @guillaumeblaquiere so EVERYTHING runs the same and now I just have to cd folder in alll my scripts or call ./folder/script.sh and it is the same across tools.  That was super confusing but glad to have them all work the same now.

Comment: Though the one caveat is I think docker run gcr.io/orderly-gcp/transferdbs blah works differently :( which is kind of odd, so not all environments match and that is where we started to test the image then moved to using google commands.  Why does google change compared to docker run commands?

Comment: or is docker run the wrong command as docker run uses files inside the image while the gcloud commands seem to use files OUTSIDE the image in the git repo.  This is the confusing piece.  Is there an equivalent docker run command I can use that uses file outside the image like google so all 3 environments match, docker run and the two glcoud commands.